# Regex for Date DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: regex, html

I have the following expression which will be used as date validation in the HTML5 "pattern" attribute.

```
?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

I want it to allow only valid dates, using "-" as a separator.
This means up to 29th in February if it's a leap year, and 30/31 for other months respectively.

Currently, it only allows years starting with 2 (2012) and months up to 12 (December).
But it limits the day to 29 regardless of which month.

Can anybody help me fix it?

Comment: Is that the whole thing? Your parentheses appear to be unbalanced or just plain missing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I must have spent too much time writing it and had left it at an incorrect stage when posting it up here. No matter now though, I have a working answer! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(0[13578]|1[02])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)/(0[13456789]|1[012])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])/02/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29/02/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. One minor issue is that you put /'s instead of -'s.

Answer (score 0):

I was linked to another great resource for validating using regular expressions.
[This](http://atomicnoggin.ca/blog/2012/06/07/the-ultimate-date-validation-regexp/) link provides the "ultimate" date validator, for many different day formats, and allows all delimiters.